# $(X\wedge Y)\wedge Z\cong X\wedge(Y\wedge Z)$ for compactly generated spaces $X,Y,Z$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show

> $(X\wedge Y)\wedge Z\cong X\wedge(Y\wedge Z)$ for compactly generated spaces $X,Y,Z$.

For this, I tried to write $(X\wedge Y)\wedge Z$ as a quotient space of the form $(X\times Y\times\ Z)/\sim$ for some equivalence relation $\sim$. So far, I get
\begin{align*}
(X\wedge Y)\wedge Z & = \left({X\times Y\over X\vee Y}\right)\wedge Z\\
& = {\left({X\times Y\times Z\over(X\vee Y)\times Z}\right)\over {X\times Y\over X\vee Y}\vee Z}.
\end{align*}
I don't know how to get further. Please help.

Edit: Even if this is not the best way to prove this, I want to know how to represent 'quotient of a quotient space' i.e., $(X/\sim_1)/\sim_2\ =\ X/\sim_3$ for given $\sim_1,\sim_2$ and some $\sim_3$.

Comment: It suffices to show that the map $X \times (Y \wedge Z) \to (X \wedge Y) \wedge Z$ is continuous, for which it suffices to show that $X \times Y \times Z \to X \times (Y \wedge Z)$ is a quotient map, which is true for $X$ (and $Z$) locally compact but maybe also more generally.